# Select table with column named "index"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a column name called "index"

```
select id, index
from item;
```

gives an error:

> Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'index'. If
>   this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and
>   parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper
>   syntax.

How can I do a select on a column named index? I'm using sqlserver 2008-R2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use square brackets to quote [reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx):

```
select id, [index]
from item
```

See also the documentation on [Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Put reserved words in brackets:

```
select id, [index]
from item
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT id, [index] FROM item
```

Reserved words used as names in SQL-Server must be enclosed in brackets.